# Problem in .txt file creation by Python in Jupyter

Tags: python

Started working with Python Files Access. I'm trying to write a file in Python, but am having a problem In file creation..

My code  In Jupyter

```
%%Writefile myfile.txt
Hello  this is rajat
i am a grate guy
and i like singing
```

Comment: Jupyter is case sensitive, use writefile with lower case.

Answer (score 0):

You should write `%%writefile` in small letters don't capitalize the "w". And separate lines of`%%writefile sample.txt` and your actual text.

It should be like this:

```
%%writefile myfile.txt
Hello this is rajat i am a grate guy and i like singing
```